# Redirect to previous page on timer script

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect

What I am trying to do is to have it when the user goes to this webpage, after 10 seconds it sends them back to the page they where previously on.

Comment: Code so far? SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get back to the page the visitor came from after 10 seconds , you can use something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.location = document.referrer}
,10000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `setTimeout` and `history.back()`

```js
(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        history.back();
    }, 10000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `setTimeout()` function for that.

```html
<html>
   <head>
   
      <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            function Redirect() {
               window.location="https://www.google.lk/";
            }
            
            document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 10 sec.");
            setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000);
         //-->
      </script>
      
   </head>
   
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

just include jquery library and add this code.
this will redirect to page declared on `window.location` after 10seconds

```
$(window).load(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location = yourpage.html
    }, 10000);

});
```